# Solving a recursion equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I'm trying to solve the following equation:
$$ f(n+1)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}f(n)}$$

with the condition:

$$ f(1)=1$$

Now I tried to put:
$$f(n)=Az^n$$

in the equation where $z$ is a parameter and $A$ is a constant.Using that and the boundary condition I found:
$$ f(n) = (3/2)^{\frac{1-n}{1+n}}$$

but that is not the answer since it doesn't give correct values of: $f(2)$,$f(3)$,...
I know the answer is:
$$f(n)=(3/2)^{1-2^{1-n}}$$

I don't know why I can't get to the answer.Please Help!

Comment: take $$a_n=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1-2^{1-n}}$$

Comment: Why did you try $f(n) = Az^n$? And how exactly did that give you your wrong answer? In any case, I would try to take logarithms of the recursion, in order to get rid of the square root.

Answer (score 0):

Take the logarithm,

$$\log f(n+1)=\log\sqrt{a f(x)},$$ or

$$g(n+1)=\frac{g(n)}2+\frac{\log a}2.$$

The general solution of this linear recurrence is

$$g(n)=\frac C{2^n}+\log a$$

and with the given initial condition $g(1)=0$,

$$g(n)=\log a\left(1-\frac2{2^n}\right),$$ or

$$f(n)=a^{1-2/2^n}.$$

---

As you can verify,

$$\sqrt{af(n)}=a^{(1+1-2/2^n)/2}=a^{1-2/2^{n+1}}=f(n+1).$$